# How to handle the Connection Object in my DAOs (Java EE)

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, web, connection

I have to create a web app that connects to a MySQL DB.
I was wondering how I should handle the connection object in my DAOs.

The application is likely to be used a few times a day by different users.

I am a bit troubled with the DAO pattern and using a static singleton. As it is a web app, I would have a connection to the DB permanently. I feel that it s not so good to keep this connection up and shared between all users sessions.

On the other hand, I'm not so sure that getting the connection and closing it every time I need to access the Db is really a better idea.

Is one way better than the other? did I forget anything that could be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you will have datasource setup in your container, and for each operation, just get connection from the datasource.  With correct transaction manager setup, connections retrieved under same transaction should be the same.  Connection pooling is normally handled in the datasource.

Comment: I have a datasource, but it's managed by a corporate framework and I don't have the sources of it, so I don't know how they manage the pooling (if they do). I have tried decompiling relevant classes but I didn't find any pooling mechanism.

Comment: well, if they has implemented a DataSource, in most case they has already properly handled that.  And, you said it is a web application and I bet it is deployed in a webapp container.  Normally datasource is in fact managed in such container which you don't really need to worry of.  I will suggest just try out the normal approach I suggested, and write a little POC to make sure it works fine.

Comment: And even it turns out that you find the data source implementation is not handling connection pooling, it is still fine.  First it doesn't affect the functionality, second, I think you can find some data source lib that decorate your existing datasource and provide connection pooling functionality (I think bonecp provide such feature)

Comment: actually the datasource is not managed by the webapp container but by this corporate framework and config files :/
there is no JNDI or any other registry to handle that as far as I know.
Anyway I'll check your proposition and see if I can use a lib to manage that, bonecp or maybe C3PO which I have used a couple of time with hibernate already
Thx

Comment: as long as you can get the reference to the datasource, it should be fine.  Many application use self-managed datasource anyway  :)